# list <li> sorting not working when use load()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several `li` inside `ul` and I use this code to sort them in ascending order by data-percentage attribute

```js
$(function() {
  $(".alll li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.alll');
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('percentage')) > ($(a).data('percentage')) ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

but when I use `$(".dayss").load("days0.php");` to load the same `li` from another page but with different data-percentage so when I want to sort it sort but in ascending in the first click and descending order in the second click and third is ascending again. I don't know what the problem is here so please any solution thank you

Comment: So you would need to call the code when the load() is done. document.ready has nothing to do with Ajax calls finishing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry i found the problem and it was the data percentage value which is php and the file that contain the values was not included so i fixed it. i am so sorry epascarello for your time. thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

load() has nothing to do with document.ready so your code is most likely executing before the load has completed. So you need to do the sorting after it is done.

```
var sortDirection = 1;
function sortLis () {
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('percentage')) > ($(a).data('percentage')) ? sortDirection : -sortDirection;
  }
  $(".alll li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.alll');
}

$(sortLis);
$(".dayss").load("days0.php", function () {
  sortDirection = 1;
  sortLis();
});
$(document).on("click", ".sortButton", function () {
  sortDirection * -1;
  sortLis();
})
```

Comment: I did this but still in the first click ascending and in the second descending.$(".j1000d").click(function(){
  $(".dayss").load("days1000.php", function() {


$(".toplii").click(function(){
     
    
        
    setTimeout(function(){
  
     
       
    $(function() {
  $(".alll li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.alll');
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('percentage')) > ($(a).data('percentage')) ? 1 : -1;
  }
});

    
  
}, 500);
 }); }); });

Comment: notice days0 doesn't change from days1000 it is the same file

Comment: So you need to keep track of the sort order and reverse it

Comment: How is this sort code work on both ways descending and ascending and notice that if i didn't use load() everything is okay!!

Comment: I have the <li> on the main page and with sort code and it work well but when i load <ul> from another page to replace the current <ul> the sort start to work on both ways.

Comment: So call the sort method... `$(sortLis);`

Comment: I used it in $(".j1000d").click(); when it clicked the sort should work

Comment: Unclear how it would have worked before since there is no click event being bound. If you are trying to bind the click, you need to use event delegation. Again none of this was in the original question.

Comment: Answer now has the basic idea. adjust the selector for click

Comment: $(".toplii").click(function(){
       
  $(".alll li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.alll');
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('percentage')) > ($(a).data('percentage')) ? 1 : -1;
  }
 });